Why script from Jupyter is not working in VS Code?
Why this  python code cannot be executed in VS Code but works in Jupyter notebook? how do you print the output?
def get_even(numbers):
    return [num for num in numbers if not num % 2]

get_even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

output expected is:
[2, 4, 6]


You need to use print (i.e. print(get_even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))). Jupyter adds a print for you (it's actually a different version of it) for the last statement of every cell if that statement does not evaluates to None.

Does this answer your question? Why do I get extra output from code using 'print' (or output at all, using 'return') at the REPL, but not in a script?

x = get_even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(x)  Output:  [2, 4, 6]
